# Is there a way to hide window while game is starting in Bevy?

Tags: bevy

When running game in Bevy: At startup, I see a big window with white rectangle in it. After a few seconds my WindowDescriptor kicks in, and the window is resized to the dimensions that I want.

Is there a way to hide the window during the loading process, so I don't see the white rectangle? Or some other way to have my own loading screen?

I see this issue on the breakout example in Bevy. I am running in Windows10 OS.

Answer (score 0):

The [window-settings example](https://github.com/bevyengine/bevy/blob/main/examples/window/window_settings.rs) now illustrates how to achieve this. Summary:

Init the window invisibly:

```rust
App::new().add_plugins((
    DefaultPlugins.set(WindowPlugin {
        primary_window: Some(Window {
            visible: false,
            ..default()
        }),
        ..default()
    }),
    FrameTimeDiagnosticsPlugin,
)).add_systems(Update, make_visible).run();
```

Then make it visible after a few frames:

```rust
fn make_visible(mut window: Query<&mut Window>, frames: Res<FrameCount>) {
    // The delay may be different for your app or system.
    if frames.0 == 3 {
        // At this point the gpu is ready to show the app so we can make the window visible.
        // Alternatively, you could toggle the visibility in Startup.
        // It will work, but it will have one white frame before it starts rendering
        window.single_mut().visible = true;
    }
}
```

I would suggest to *additionally* implement a loading screen. This can be done similarly to the [game-menu example](https://github.com/bevyengine/bevy/blob/main/examples/games/game_menu.rs).